# compare rows of a file with awk

Tags: file, awk, rows

I have a file with several fields. One of the fields is IP address and another one is flow sent from that IP address in bytes. Now I want to list IP addresses that have sent the most flow size. For this I need to compare value of IP address fields.

Please advise me on how to do this using `awk`.

Comment: Give some example file, how you like the output to be, and what you have tried to solve it.

Comment: Instead of `awk` you could use `sort -rnk $FLOW_COLUMN | head -n $LINES_TO_OUTPUT`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the format of your file. Assume that the two fields are splited by '\t'.
The code is like this. The output file is the IP addresses with flow size in a descending order.

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -F"\t" '
    {
        ip_add[$1] += $2
    }
    END{
        for (ip in ip_add)
            print ip"\t"ip_add[ip]
    }
' | sort +1nr > output
```